# same code different steps two different outcomes

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, data-analysis

question :
so despite these two being the same when I execute both code I get two different graphs. someone please explain why.

[code1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4kJP.png)

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB2ae.png)

I don't understand why the output is different considering they are both operating on the same data. The only difference is that one has been broken up into easier steps?

Answer (score 0):

In the first graph you use .head() and it takes the first 5 rows of the dataframe. In the second graph you use .head() but don't overwrite the dataframe. You only call it and don't assign it.